# Base64 Decode image string

Tags: php, image, encode, radix

I would like to decode the following to display an image.

```
$i = '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQIAHAAcAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB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=';

$decoded = base64_decode($i);
header("Content-type:image/jpg");
echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$decoded.' />';
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? When I decode it using an online converter it displays the image correctly.

It was converted originally by uploading the image to an online convertor.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Are you sure base 64 string is valid?

Comment: I think there must be a bug in the string yes as now I can get half the image appearing.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the header as jpeg, but then you're echoing an image tag.